# Are my external disks fried? Can they be salvaged, formatted or partitioned back to Exfat?

Tags: disk-utility, partition, external-disk, error, disk-format

**TL;DR**

I have two brand new 2TB JMicron Generic Media external 2.5" HDDs and one old 128MB flash drive. All three were usable (they've been used for transferring files, not Time Machine). Now both the 2TB are unusable and my flash drive has been reduced to 8MB (also unusable). When connecting any of the drives to my Mac Book Pro (Retina mid-2015, 10.10.3), I get the dialog box saying "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer." "[Initialize | Ignore | Eject]".

**Questions**

1. Are my external disks fried?
2. Can they be salvaged, formatted or paritioned back to Exfat?

**How the 128MB pendrive got reduced to 8MB and now unusable**

On the MBP, I was transferring some files onto the 128MB pendrive but for some reason the transfer was unsuccessful. I think I may have disconnected the flash drive without ejecting. Upon connecting it to my Windows laptop I saw that it was reduced to 8MB and no longer usable (can't be formatted). I should mention that straight after connecting to the Windows laptop, I got a notification that a Chipsbnk driver was installed. This was while one of the unusable 2TB disks was connected as well. Perhaps this resulted in a power/voltage power problem...?

**How the two 2TB External 2.5" HDDs became unusable**

After trying to partition the 2TB drives they both became immediately unusable.

**Attempts to resolve**

I tried using the Undelete Plus software on Windows but after scanning (all three drives), I couldn't recover anything. For the 128MB flash pendrive, on Windows I used the `clean` command via Diskpart on the CMD software. However, I wasn't able to `create partition primary` or `convert to mbr`. Switching back to Mac, I tried `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk1 bs=8m` but this hasn't changed anything.

I also couldn't complete this on the 2TB drives because it would take >100 days (I've mentioned this in my question, linked above). After many attempts to repair/resolve the 2TB drives, I still wasn't able to format/partition them on Mac or Windows. Please see my previous question for what I tried: [Unusable 2.5" external HDD. Partition failed with the error -69760: Unable to write to the last block of the device. Exfat only? Repairable?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391754/unusable-2-5-external-hdd-partition-failed-with-the-error-69760-unable-to-wr)

NB. I'm not 100% sure if there is a link between what happened to my 2TB drives and the 128MB flash drive.

**I may be wrong but here's why I think these drives are not fried yet**

A few years ago, I frequently transferred files back and forth between my MBP and my Windows laptop. At that time I used a 32GB Transcend flash pendrive until that pendrive completely stopped working — I can't remember exactly why but I think I may have disconnected it while a transfer was apparently still going on. When I connect this pendrive to my MBP, I couldn't find it listed under `diskutil list`. Neither does it show up on my Windows computer management software. So I assume this drive has been completely fried, even though the blue light on the pendrive still blinks upon connecting to a computer. Whereas the three drives mentioned above are still listed under `diskutil list`.

[image]

Comment: I'd forget the pen drive, it's probably toast… but the JMicrons, what are you connecting them with? Always the same cable/port etc? The 'unable to write to last block' error is usually an SATA cabling issue.

Comment: @Tetsujin, With the original cables that came with them, they look like USB 3.0. Tried on both USB ports either side of the MBP. Also tried on different ports on the Windows laptop. Tried swapping the cables too. Apparently these JMicrons are Exfat only, but now I can't even get them back to Exfat.

Comment: If the units won't strip apart easily enough to try them as internal drives in something, I'd at least try different cables.

Comment: @Tetsujin, Thank you for your response. Photo added - stripping the casing doesn't seem easy. The two cables are male USB 3.0 on one end and USB-B on the other. Similar to this: https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/usb-cables/9015064/ — I trust you've seen my original attempts in the answer (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391754/unusable-2-5-external-hdd-partition-failed-with-the-error-69760-unable-to-wr). Just trying to understand here, if the disks worked at first instance and are now unusable but still listed under `diskutil list`, how does changing the cables help prove anything?

Comment: "The 'unable to write to last block' error is usually an SATA cabling issue" <- That. tbh, if they're supposed to be ExFAT only, there's some fiddling going on inside the box which you'd only discover once stripped down. Their web page doesn't give me much confidence either  - https://www.jmicron.com/solution - I think they're cheapskating & hoping the end user doesn't notice :\

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure if it's their fault or the Mainland Chinese manufacturer's (that assembled/configured the controller  with the case and hard disk) fault. I briefly enquired about this with @Allan in the chat within my previous question. We were also concluding somewhat that ExFat only could mean there's someone in the supply chain who's cheapskating. I've already emailed JMicron but haven't heard back. I've now emailed them again.